# Rак вместо alert выводить сообщение в блок с заданным классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня идет проверка при отправке формы с выводом сообщения об ошибке через alert. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вместо alert выводить это сообщение в блок с классом `.error-msg`?

```js
$("#EasyNewsletterSubscriptionForm").submit(function(event) {
  $('#EasyNewsletterSubscriptionSubmit').click();
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#EasyNewsletterSubscriptionSubmit').on('click', function() {
  var email_validate = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
  if ((document.getElementById("YourName").value == 0) || (document.getElementById("YourEmail").value.length == 0)) {
    alert("<?php echo $EasyNewsletterSubscription_Error1; ?>")
  } else if (!document.getElementById("YourEmail").value.match(email_validate)) {
    alert("<?php echo $EasyNewsletterSubscription_Error2; ?>")
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=module/easynewslettersubscription/subscribecustomer',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#EasyNewsletterSubscriptionForm').serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        $('#EasyNewsletterSubscriptionSuccess').html("<div class='alert alert-success ens_success' style='display: none;'>" + response + "</div>");
        $('.ens_success').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#YourName').val('');
        $('#YourEmail').val('');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="error-msg"> </div>
    <form id="EasyNewsletterSubscriptionForm">
      <div id="EasyNewsletterSubscriptionSuccess"></div>
      <input type="text" name="YourName" id="YourName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="YourEmail" id="YourEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" />
      <br />
      <a id="EasyNewsletterSubscriptionSubmit" class="btn btn-default">
        <?php echo $EasyNewsletterSubscription_SubscribeNow; ?>
      </a>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо alert

```
$('.error-msg').html('<?php echo $EasyNewsletterSubscription_Error1; ?>')
```

Comment: как заметил 1111100000 - если блока нет, то это дело упадет с ошибкой ".html() not a function" т.к. $('.error-msg) будет пустым

Answer (score 3):

Убедитесь, что такой блок уже присутствует, когда вызывается:

```
function showError (msg = '') {
  let element = document.querySelector('.error-msg')
  if(element) {
    element.innerHTML(`<span>${msg}</span>`)
    element.classList.add('shown')
  }
}
```